# How can I copy AWS Backup vault files to a local server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-backup

How can I copy the backup files created by AWS Backup to an on-premise server?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to restore AWS resource from vault first, it will generate an AMI or EBS or any other kind of resource you did backup.
With this resource restored you will need to create an instance from it or using it to get the files you are looking for.

On the link below you can read more about how to restore from AWS Backup.

[Restore a Backup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/restore-resource.html)

Comment: Thanks.  So for an RDS backup, I can't just get it directly from an S3 bucket?  It sound like it might be easier just to schedule a snapshot and download.

Comment: You are correct, you can't get it directly from S3. AWS Backup and even RDS snapshot uses S3 infrastructure, but you don't see it. You can't have access on it. You will need to create an instance from your snapshot first.